# variation on the image of a functor

Tags: category-theory

It is well known that the naive "image" of a functor $F\colon C\to D$, i.e., all the images of objects in C and all images of morhipsms in C, need not constitute a category. It is then natural to define the image of $F$ as the smallest subcategory of $D$ containing all actual images of objects and morphisms. This is a typical example of something done often in category theory (i.e., many adjoints are constructed like this): Look at the naive thing you get, realize it does not have the properties you want it to have, thus replace it by the (in some sense) smallest larger object that does have the properties you want it to have. However, there is also the possibility of replacing the problematic object by the largest smaller object with the desired properties.

So, is there a notion of image of functor where instead of adding all compositions of actual images of morphisms (thus perhaps adding morphisms not 'really' in the image) one considers the true images but only of some of the morphisms in the domain category? Of course, some 'real' images may be missing, and thus such a notion of image will not factorize the given functor (though it may do so when considering partial functors). It may also be that there is no single canonical choice of which morphisms to choose, leading to several different notions of such image. One extreme (and useless) possibility is to only consider the true images of the identities. This is guaranteed to produce a subcategory, albeit a boring one. I'll be interesting in any lead along this direction, i.e., any nice choice of morphisms in $D$ whose true images are to be taken, leading to a nice concept. References or general thoughts very much appreciated.

Comment: "It may also be that there is no single canonical choice of which morphisms to choose"
Indeed, take $\clubsuit \leftarrow \diamondsuit → \heartsuit$, and map the morphisms to (1, 0) and (0, 1) in $ℤ/(2) × ℤ/(2)$. You could of course just ask for the maximal subcategories of the naive image, or subcategories of the domain such that the naive image is a subcategory, but different maximals surely don't need to be equivalent (eg. map the coproduct of two different monoids-as-categories to their product in an obvious way).

Comment: @user54748: what? What do the playing card symbols mean?

Comment: This is supposed to be an abstract category freely generated by a span. The names of the objects are irrelevant. Usually such a category is depicted as $\bullet \leftarrow \bullet \rightarrow \bullet$.